# how to use dll?

Tags: c++

i have have a program/project in vs2008 that uses a third party static lib. Now, it has come to my attention that i need to offer some api's via a dll. Apparently a thrid party program will use my dll via the apis i will provide.

Can anyone give me some direction as to what I need to do? would i need to just create a dll in vs2008 and just copy and paste my method logic in the apis that i provide?

are there any potential issues i need to worry about?

thank you

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check out [this MSDN tutorial](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235636(VS.80).aspx) on creating & using DLLs.

There are unfortunately many potential issues to think about.  A very brief and by no means complete list of the ones that pop in to my head:

- You need to be aware of [potential errors passing CRT objects across DLL boundaries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235460(VS.80).aspx)
- If you allocate objects in one module and deallocate them in the other, your DLL and the client code must link to the same CRT
- It is very important that you keep the interface seperate from the implementation in your DLLs header files.  This means you often can't do thing like [use std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322095/why-does-this-program-crash-passing-of-stdstring-between-dlls) as function parameters, or even as private member variables.

If I think of more or find more links, I'll add them.

Comment: currently i use std::String everywhere in my code. but i reckon when i do the api iterfaces i would need to use const char * perhaps to do the same thing?

Comment: Yeah, if your functions take string parameters you can & should just use `const char*` parameters instead of `string` s.  The functions that return `string`s are more problematic.  You need to somehow either allocate a `char` buffer and return a `char*` (you will need to be careful of the second point above) or accept a pre-allocated buffer and fill it in.