# STL Vector Corruption Across VS Projects

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, vector

I have a Visual Studio 2005 solution with several projects that build independently of each other. The main project statically links the other projects. I'm getting very strange STL vector corruption in one of those statically-linked libraries. For example, I declare a std::vector and then perform a `sort( thatVector.begin(), thatVector.end() )`, but when I debug it and look at the disassembly, I see this:

```
std::vector<SomeOtherClass<SomeOtherTemplateType>,std::allocator<SomeOtherClass<SomeOtherTemplateType> > >::begin
```

The incredibly odd thing is that `SomeOtherClass` and `SomeOtherTemplate` are declared in the main project, so this library should have absolutely no knowledge of them whatsoever.

I've tried freezing all other threads, thinking that perhaps one of them was corrupting `thatVector`, but no dice. I'm at a complete loss. Has anyone experienced something like this?

Compile info: 
- main program /Zi, custom optimization (basically a debuggable release build)
- static library /Zi, /Od

Link info:
/DEBUG

Comment: With what template do you declare std::vector<?> thatVector?

Comment: Do you get the same template instantiation information with optimization off?

Comment: Check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/433274/c-parameters-value-changes-between-stack-frames-in-stdvector/433405#433405

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that library and program have been compiled with different compiler options. As the result you've got different iterators implementation but with the same signature. It is [known problem](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/352699/secure-scl-is-broken-in-release-builds) and Microsoft recommends to compile several versions of statically linked libraries and link executable with appropriate one.

Answer (score 0):

A vector is a templated type, meaning that every piece of code that refers to the vector must know the complete type.  Not only can your library knwo about SomeOtherClass and SomeOtherTemplateType, they *must* know about them in order to refer to a vector of them.

In this case, the complete type of your vector is:

```
std::vector<SomeOtherClass<SomeOtherTemplateType>,std::allocator<SomeOtherClass<SomeOtherTemplateType> > >
```

...which is probably declared in your code something like this:

```
vector<SomeOtherClass<SomeOtherTemplateType> > thatVector;
```

...with the allocator resolving to a default template argument.

Now, on to your corruption problem.  There isn't much information to go on about the *nature* of the corruption, so I am going to make a few assumptions.  Nameley that you allocate the vector in one module and try to do something with it (like `push_back` in to it) in another module, and that it is when you do something in the other module when the corruption actually occurs.  Frustratingly, in many of these cases the corruption isn't detected or reported at the moment when the corruption occurs.  It often is detected much later in totally unrelated code.

If the above assumptions are correct, I have 2 suggestions as to the possible cause:

1. The modules are not linked to the same version & flavor of the runtime libraries.  Try making sure that each module links to the same CRT (for example, Multithreaded Debug DLL under Windows) and try again.  Most of the time, this is the problem.
2. You are using different compilers (or different versions of the same compiler) to create the different modules.  In this case, a vector looks like one thing to one module and looks like something else to another module.  There are many threads that indirrectly discuss this kind of problem, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2343245/can-you-please-explain-this-c-delete-problem/2343366#2343366) for one example.

Comment: I'm actually allocating the vector and using it in the same module. Yet somehow when I step through it, it contains classes that don't exist in that module.