# Managed c++ std::string not accessible in unmanaged c++

Tags: c++, managed, stdstring

In unmanaged c++ dll i have a function which takes constant `std::string` as argument

```
 Prototype : void read ( const std::string &imageSpec_ )
```

I call this function from managed c++ dll by passing a `std::string`.
When i debug the unmanaged c++ code the parameter `imageSpec_` shows the value correctly but does not allow me to copy that value in other variable.

```
 imageSpec_.copy( sFilename, 4052 );
```

It shows length of `imageSpec_`     as 0(zero).
If i try copying like `std::string sTempFileName(imageSpec_);` this statement string new string is a empty string.

But for `std::string sTempFileName(imageSpec_.c_str());` this statement string gets copied correctly. i.e. with charpointer string is copied correctly.

Copying this way will need a major change in unmanaged c++ code.
I am building unmanaged code in Visual studio 6.0 and managed c++ in Visual studio 2008.
Is there any specific setting or code change in managed c++ that will solve the issue?

Comment: Is it "Managed C++" or C++/CLI ?

Comment: Are you sure that mixing VC++6.0 and VC++ 2008 objects is supported?

Answer (score 1):

> I am building unmanaged code in Visual
>   studio 6.0 and managed c++ in Visual studio 2008.

You are trying to copy the `std::string` implementation of Visual studio 6.0 into the `std::string` implmentation of Visual Studio 2008. If you want to pass C++ objects across DLL boundaries, you have to be very careful - you must build both side of the boundary using exactly the same object layout (which is compiler specific) and library implementation and build them against compatible runtimes.

If you want to create a .dll that is useable from code compiled with a different compiler/library from that .dll, a pure C interface is the way to go.

---

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322095/why-does-this-program-crash-passing-of-stdstring-between-dlls) related question.