# Heap corruption when using DLL code

Tags: c++, debugging, dll, heap-memory, heap-corruption

I have some code that I need to place in a common library dll. This code, a class `CalibrationFileData`, works perfectly fine when it's built as part of the current project. However, if `CalibrationFileData` is built in the common library, the program crashes, mentioning heap corruptions.

I have made sure that all allocations and deallocations occur within the class, with appropriate accessors, etc. Still, the problem won't go away. Just in case it makes any difference, I am sometimes passing vectors of pairs, definitely not plain old data, but the vector manipulation only occurs through the accessors, so there shouldn't be any allocation happening across modules.

Anything I'm missing?

**Edit:**  The vectors are these:

```
std::vector<std::pair<CvPoint2D32f, CvPoint3D32f>>* extrinsicCorrespondences;
std::vector<int>* pointsPerImage;
```

I shouldn't need to worry about deep copies, since they're not heap allocated, right? Incidentally, I tried using *pointers* to vectors, as above, to sidestep the problem, but it didn't make a difference anyway.

Comment: I'm concerned about the vector itself. Because it's a template, the DLL and the EXE could have different instances of the vector code. This may be what trajanfoe is hinting at - not sure. Also, vector-of-pairs-of-what? Do the pairs contain pointers to heap-allocated objects?

Answer (score 4):

Check the compile flags match between the library and the executable. For example, on Windows ensure you're using the same C Runtime Library (CRT) (/MD vs /MT). Check for warnings from the linker.

Comment: +1 I second this, particularly when using the Standard Template Library.

Comment: /MT is not enough - it would still produce two "instances" of the memory allocator. /MD (or /MDd) is a way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Are you certain that when you take ownership of the contents of the `vector` objects, within your methods, you are deep-copying them into your instance variables?

Answer (score 0):

you should check deep copies inside vector object,it is pertain with deepcopy i think

Answer (score 0):

Could it be different values defined for _SECURE_SCL in the two projects ?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you missed some piece of the client's code that tries to deallocate a memory that your DLL allocated or vice versa.

Perhaps the easiest thing to do would be to ensure that both client and the DLL use the same memory allocator. Not just the same kind, but the same actual "instance" of the allocator. On Visual C++, this is most easily achieved by **both** client and DLL using a "Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)" or "Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)" runtime library.

Answer (score 0):

In the command line option, in visual studio remove this _SECURE_SCL. Mostly this crash is caused by  _SECURE_SCL mismatch among the details. More details can be found here: http://kmdarshan.com/blog/?p=3830

Answer (score 0):

You should distinguish between *tightly coupled* and *loosely coupled* `DLL`s.

**Tightly coupled** `DLL`s mean that

> the `DLL` is built with the exact same compiler version, packing and
>   calling convention settings, library options as the application, and
>   both dynamically link to the runtime library (`/MD` compiler option).
>   This lets you pass objects back and forth including `STL` containers,
>   allocate `DLL` objects from inside the application, derive from base
>   classes in the other module, do just about everything you could
>   without using `DLL`s. The disadvantage is that you can no longer
>   deploy the `DLL` independently of the main application. Both must be
>   built together. The `DLL` is just to improve your process startup time
>   and working set, because the application can start running before
>   loading the `DLL` (using the `/delayload` linker option). Build times
>   are also faster than a single module, especially when whole program
>   optimization is used. But optimization doesn't take place across the
>   application-DLL boundary. And any non-trivial change will still
>   require rebuilding both.

In case of **loosely coupled** `DLL`s, then

> When exporting DLL functions, it's best if they accept only integral
>   data types, i.e. `int` or pointers.

With reference, for example, to strings, then:

> When you need to pass a string, pass it as a `const char *`. When you
>   need the `DLL` function to return a string, pass to the DLL a `char *`
>   pointer to a pre-allocated buffer, where the `DLL` would write the
>   string.

Finally, concerning memory allocation, then:

> Never use memory allocated by the `DLL` outside of the `DLL`'s own
>   functions, and never pass by value structures that have their own
>   constructor/destructor.

**References**

[Heap corruption when returning from function inside a dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13679104/heap-corruption-when-returning-from-function-inside-a-dll)

[Can I pass std::string to a DLL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347355/i-can-pass-stdstring-for-a-dll-and-what-i-can-do-with-dll%C2%B4s)