# Create dynamic library with opencv inside C++

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I have built a Project with Opencv inside then using it in C#.

 
But i cant package my project include opencv libs into Dynamic DLL then calling it in C#.

Can somebody give me some hints? :(

My Code:

```
#include "opencv\cv.h"
#include "opencv\highgui.h"
using namespace cv;
extern "C" _declspec(dllexport) string OpenCVTest(string fileName)
{   

     Mat img = imread(fileName);    
     IplImage image = img;  
     cvShowImage("Hello world", &image);
     cvWaitKey(0);
     cvDestroyAllWindows();

     return "";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use Pinvoke technology which let you call c++ functions from c# code .

if you have such a function written in c++

```
extern "C" {

MYAPI void print_line(const char* str);

}
```

you can define a prototype for it in c#

```
[DllImport("NativeLib.dll")]
private static extern void print_line(string str);
```

and then you can use it in c# as a normal function

if you want to pass a std::string from c# then you must use a marshaller for it please refer to this

[Custom Marshaler for PInvoke with std::string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17099611/custom-marshaler-for-pinvoke-with-stdstring)

Comment: But i cant import OpenCV Lib to C#.
How can i package Opencv lib into my project C++ Dynamic DLL?

Comment: you have to link your c++ library against opencv and offcourse these dlls have to be available to the c# exe upon execuation