# Unable to pass std::wstring across DLL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, dll

I've set up a project in Visual Studio 2010 to write unit tests against an existing MFC DLL. I'm using a single-header unit test framework, and linked to the MFC DLL's lib wrapper from the unit test project. I'm trying to construct a class that takes a `std::wstring` in it's constructor. Here's what my test looks like:

```
TEST_CASE("MyProject/MyTest", "Do the test.")
{
    MockDbService mockDbService;
    Foobar foo(L"{F00DFACE-FEED-DEAD-BEEF-C0FFEEDECADE}", mockDbService);

    foo.loadObject();

    REQUIRE(mockDbService.getMethodInvokeCount("query()") >= 1);
}
```

Where `Foobar` is the class exported from the MFC DLL under test. However, the test framework reports an unexpected exception. I tracked it down to `std::wstring`'s copy constructor when copying the string to `Foobar`'s constructor. The MSVC debugger reports the source string as `<Bad Ptr>`.

I created a dummy constructor, `Foobar::Foobar(long num, IDbService& db)` and all the values (including the `IDbService&`) come across just fine.

Both the MFC DLL and my unit test EXE are sharing a property sheet which should keep the compiler flags equivalent. I'm building and running the test in debug mode. Any ideas why the `std::wstring` can't copy across the DLL?

Comment: Are you dynamically linking both the EXE and the DLL with the debug version of the CRT? (`/MDd`)

Comment: @Mr.C64 Wow, that was it. My unit test project was using `/MD` and the MFC DLL was `/MDd`. I'd love a brief explanation as an answer so I can understand it; and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: I added a brief explanation. Basically, I think the problem in your case is that debug-build's `std::wstring` has a different implementation than release-build's `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You should check that both the EXE and the DLL are *dynamically linked* with the *same debug CRT* (`/MDd` compiler option). Make sure that also other settings like `_HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING` are the same for both the EXE and the DLL.

(A shortcut could be to just use `const wchar_t*` instead of `std::wstring` at the class interface, and just build a `std::wstring` from the raw pointer inside constructor's body).

**EDIT**: You confirmed that CRT mismatch (i.e. EXE built with `/MD` vs. DLL built with `/MDd`) was the problem. The fact is that the same class name `std::wstring` means two different classes in debug builds (`/MDd`) and in release builds (`/MD`). In fact, in debug builds there can be additional mechanics inside the class implementation to help debugging; this mechanics can introduce inefficiencies, so it's removed in release builds. So, the internal structure of debug build's `std::wstring` is different from release build's `std::wstring` (e.g. if you try to print the raw `sizeof` of `std::wstring` instances, you can find different numbers in release builds and debug builds). So, the EXE built with `/MD` was expecting release-build's `std::wstring`; instead the DLL built with `/MDd` was expecting debug-build's `std::wstring`: there is a mismatch between these two expectations (one module is expecting class `X` but the other module is giving class `Y`) and so you have a crash.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. In that case, my problem is exactly that which I found earlier: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2322095/why-does-this-program-crash-passing-of-stdstring-between-dlls?rq=1 But both my projects were built in Debug so I didn't think it was related. According to what you're saying, I was using the release build of the CRT even with debug projects. Thanks again.

Comment: Yes, `/MD` is dynamic linking to release CRT DLL; `/MDd` is dynamic linking to debug CRT DLL.

Comment: I also hit with:  HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING=0 in one project and not in the other ( once we started using google tests )