# "Corruption of the heap" error when returning std::vector<Point> from function

Tags: c++, dll, stl, heap-corruption

I'm facing heap corruption error: I have a dll and TestAPP.

1. `vector<Point> vInPts;` // Test Application - dumping inputs like below

   ```
   vInPts.push_back(Point(730,405));
   vInPts.push_back(Point(319,680));
   vInPts.push_back(Point(292,757));
   vInPts.push_back(Point(318,756));
   vInPts.push_back(Point(726,736));
   vInPts.push_back(Point(344,731));
   ```
2. `vector<Point> vOutPts;`
3. Calling DLL -> copying same `vInPts` vector to `vOutPts` vector in DLL" -> When returning from this function to TestApp -> Heap Error arises. Now Facing Heap Error [image]

How can I fix this Heap Error?
Thanks in advance !!!

Comment: How are you copying into the output vector?

Comment: @juanchopanza i am doing in proper way, and i am very sure that copying wont be the problem in my case. " I tested " even if i pass only the input vector to dll and doing nothing with the input vector and when controls go to the TestAPP - same Heap Error comes .

Comment: Which runtime are you using? Are you using the same runtime for the dll and the application?

Comment: @TobiasSchlegel yes both runtime are same.

Comment: @Pixel, the runtime libraries must be the same instance, not just the same type.

Comment: @Pixel: please double check the command-line options (e.g. a potential error may be mixing `/MD` and `/MDd`). Consider also [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15177907/unable-to-pass-stdwstring-across-dll) and [related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15178021/1629821) on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 2):

It would be interesting to read the actual definition of your `Point` class. Is it properly copyable?

Moreover, since you are using a DLL and an EXE with STL classes, make sure that both the DLL and the EXE are built with **dynamic linking** to the **same flavor of the CRT** (e.g. both are built with the same version of the C++ compiler, and with the same settings, e.g. release build DLL with release build EXE, etc.)

In fact, STL classes's *implementations* differ in release builds and debug builds (e.g. in debug builds there is more overhead for checkings like iterator validation, etc.).
If a STL class is shared between the EXE and the DLL, it must be the *same* class, not classes with the same name but a different implementations.